# Whatzit? Name this dryer or washer thing-a-ma-bob

Tags: dryer, washer

I am victorious! I have my new LG washer and gas dryer installed. After a weekend of pain and suffering. Well, at least a few trips to Home Depot.

All's done except...I'm left with this one part. I don't see it listed as an accessory in either of my manuals. Maybe it wasn't supposed to come with them and the delivery people just tossed it in?

Anyone know what this is for? It's about 12" long and appears to be a braided wire cable with a plastic sleeve. A flat hook on one end and an eyelet on the other.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That may very well be a washer tub restraint device. The tub in a washer machine is often mounted in a way that takes up vibration during normal operation. During shipping from the factory additional items are added to the washer to restrain motion in the tub to prevent knocking around and/or damage. This cable hook device could be one of those restraint devices.

If a local delivery service brought the washer to your house they very often remove the restraint devices and other shipment items. This could include tapes that hold doors shut, ties that bind up wires, tub restraints.....it could be that the service people didn't extract all devices.

Answer (score 4):

It might be a restraint to prevent a stacked washer/dryer combo from toppling in the event of an earthquake or a child climbing it - in that case it would have on end bolted into a stud, and the other would connect to the higher device (usually the dryer) in the stack. If not stacked, not needed.

On the other hand, if the hooked end is greasy, @Michael Karas is probably right.