# Moving a washer and dryer when relocating across the country

Tags: dryer, washer, relocating

I have been contemplating accepting a job offer on the opposite side of USA. If everything works out, I was thinking about putting all my belongings to a couple of u-haul u-boxes and have them shipped.

So for this reason I wanted to ask if I needed to somehow secure the drums on my washer and dryer?

Both are electric (not gas) and of the front-loading variety.

Comment: Unless you are deeply in love with them, selling here and buying there may make more sense than shipping them.

Comment: Thank you for the input, @Ecnerwal. Selling them before the move does look like a good option.

Comment: Inconclusively relevant: [Whatzit? washer-thing-a-ma-bob?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/47993/whatzit-name-this-dryer-or-washer-thing-a-ma-bob?rq=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use them to avoid not having any means of recompense from the shipper, or from the manufacturer by voiding the warranty.

If you didn't save yours, [replacement shipping bolts](https://www.google.com/search?q=replacement%20shipping%20bolts&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) can be obtained from most appliance parts suppliers (the label with your model number is probably behind the door).

---

I would not be concerned, if you're the one carefully putting it into a <strike>box</strike> truck and also the one taking it out (Edit: and the one doing the driving).

<strike>The shipping bolts are for keeping it in sellable condition, even after it falls off the forklift a few times.</strike>

Upon further [research](http://www.automaticwasher.org/cgi-bin/TD/TD-VIEWTHREAD.cgi?34150), the shipping bolts for a front loading washing machine keep the mounting springs from receiving excessive tension when bouncing up and down in transit. I will amend my answer by saying that if *I* were to be the one driving the truck, it would be fine (*you* may want to reconsider).

Comment: Thanks Mazura, so the shipping bolts might not be needed for a regular cross country move where I load and unload the container?

Comment: @x457812 [I think](http://www.automaticwasher.org/cgi-bin/TD/TD-VIEWTHREAD.cgi?34150) they should be fine, but you may want to check the manual (which prob says *don't without them* to cover their liability). You may have a hard time suing the trucking company if you don't use them where the mfg says you should of. I've thrown WMs in the back of my van and they still worked (but I did the **driving**, loading and unloading...) If you have them, use them. If not, roll the dice or buy some.

Comment: If you saved them, great. If not, they should be available from any appliance parts supplier. Moving things in your van or pickup truck is NOT the same as bouncing along in a container truck (or a portable container riding on a flatbed) with a much stiffer suspension as it goes over the bumpy road (truck driver seats have their own suspension...) If you knew most of the trip would be by rail (intermodal freight!), that would be a lot better, actually, but you never really know HOW it will get there (you just hope that it actually DOES.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- I'd still put the shipping bolts in for a rail intermodal (COFC or TOFC) move; while you don't get a ton of up-and-down bumpiness on the RR unless you're dealing with rough or otherwise not-so-great track or a car with a dodgy suspension, slack action (fore-and-aft) is a constant in rail shipments -- the end-of-car cushions take up much of it, but can only do so much.